# How to understand whether the visitor is Googlebot or not ? ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, web-crawler, googlebot

How to understand whether the visitor is Googlebot or not ? ASP.net 4.0 & C#

I mean i want to understand that if the visitor is Googlebot or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Googlebot") != -1)
{
  // google!
}
```

I think, according to the headers supplied by [this website](http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/internet/google/googlebot-spoofer/)

Answer (score 0):

**You need to check the request headers**

Each time something requests your website it gives up some information itself, as per @Brads answer you're checking whether whatever is requesting your site is calling itself 'Googlebot'.  Of course this can be a lie - so you can't place any great trust within this value.